# RMarkdown automatic anchor-section

Tags: r, r-markdown

Well, I've been working with Markdown for a year and today, suddenly, next to the headings an a tag has been automatically added.

Someone would know why these anchors have been generated automatically and how I could remove them?

Pd: one way to solve it is with h1,h2, etc., but then with the pdf output the index is eliminated, so it would not really solve the problem.

[image: Output]

[image: Markdown file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [new feature](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/releases) in rmarkdown 2.5.

You can change this in your YAML header at the top of your rmd file:

```
  html_document:
    anchor_sections: false
```