# Hashtag appears in R Markdown html

Tags: r, header, r-markdown, knitr

This is a very recent thing, but whenever I generate an R notebook into HTML, I see a hashtag symbol when I put my cursor on the title.

```
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

# Hello
```

And when this renders, I see a hashtag when I place my cursor by Hello.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is affecting my website, which I use R markdown to generate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64616004/rmarkdown-automatic-anchor-section

Comment: Gah. Thank you. It was really hard to Google this one.